# What's the difference between a DJ mix and a regular compilation album?

Tags: dj, compilations

I’ve always been confused about the difference between a *DJ mix* and just any regular type of compilation album.

The newest DJ Kicks got me even more confused though: [DJ Koze "DJ Kicks (50th Anniversary)"](http://www.vinyl-digital.com/Hip-Hop-Rap/DJ-Kicks-50th-Anniversary.html)

> The idea is more to create the appearance of a radio show, in the vein of John Peel for example.

Is a DJ mix just a personally curated compilation album?

What’s the difference between a DJ mix and a regular compilation album?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A DJ mix generally means it was created live, in one sitting and the tracks are usually blended together to mix together seamlessly. A compilation album on the other hand, keeps the tracks separate and they are generally not mixed together. Both are meant to be experienced as a whole, although the later is meant to be picked apart as individual tracks with varying degrees of success as an entire production.

Answer (score 0):

A [compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilation_album) is a more global term that covers all kinds of albums that include various tracks according to a theme ("best-of", original soundtrack of a movie, christmas songs, 2017 super hits, etc.).

A DJ mix *is* a particular type of compilation.
The tracks are not necessarily blended together as you can notice in [your example](http://www.vinyl-digital.com/Hip-Hop-Rap/DJ-Kicks-50th-Anniversary.html). In addition to what a standard compilation could be, a DJ mix may feature unreleased versions of the tracks, remixed by this DJ or another one.
It is also a way to attract fans of the DJ by saying: "these tracks are selected by the DJ you like, so you will like them".